# MongoDB into AWS Redshift

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We've got a pretty big MongoDB instance with sharded collections. It's reached a point where it's becoming too expensive to rely on MongoDB query capabilities (including aggregation framework) for insight to the data.

I've looked around for options to make the data available and easier to consume, and have settled on two promising options:

1. AWS Redshift
2. Hadoop + Hive

We want to be able to use a SQL like syntax to analyze our data, and we want close to real time access to the data (a few minutes latency is fine, we just don't want to wait for the whole MongoDB to sync overnight).

As far as I can gather, for option 2, one can use this https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop to move data over from MongoDB to a Hadoop cluster.

I've looked high and low, but I'm struggling to find a similar solution for getting MongoDB into AWS Redshift. From looking at Amazon articles, it seems like the correct way to go about it is to use AWS Kinesis to get the data into Redshift. That said, I can't find any example of someone that did something similar, and I can't find any libraries or connectors to move data from MongoDB into a Kinesis stream. At least nothing that looks promising.

Has anyone done something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up coding up our own migrator using NodeJS. 
I got a bit irritated with answers explaining what redshift and MongoDB is, so I decided I'll take the time to share what I had to do in the end.

**Timestamped data**

Basically we ensure that all our MongoDB collections that we want to be migrated to tables in redshift are timestamped, and indexed according to that timestamp.

**Plugins returning cursors**

We then code up a plugin for each migration that we want to do from a mongo collection to a redshift table. Each plugin returns a cursor, which takes the last migrated date into account (passed to it from the migrator engine), and only returns the data that has changed since the last successful migration for that plugin.

**How the cursors are used**

The migrator engine then uses this cursor, and loops through each record. 
It calls back to the plugin for each record, to transform the document into an array, which the migrator then uses to create a delimited line which it streams to a file on disk. We use tabs to delimit this file, as our data contained a lot of commas and pipes.

**Delimited exports from S3 into a table on redshift**

The migrator then uploads the delimited file onto S3, and runs the redshift copy command to load the file from S3 into a temp table, using the plugin configuration to get the name and a convention to denote it as a temporary table.

So for example, if I had a plugin configured with a table name of `employees`, it would create a temp table with the name of `temp_employees`.

Now we've got data in this temp table. And the records in this temp table get their ids from the originating MongoDB collection. This allows us to then run a delete against the target table, in our example, the employees table, where the id is present in the temp table. **If any of the tables don't exist, it gets created on the fly, based on a schema provided by the plugin**. And so we get to insert all the records from the temp table into the target table. This caters for both new records and updated records. We only do soft deletes on our data, so it'll be updated with an `is_deleted` flag in redshift.

Once this whole process is done, the migrator engine stores a timestamp for the plugin in a redshift table, in order to keep track of when the migration last run successfully for it. This value is then passed to the plugin the next time the engine decides it should migrate data, allowing the plugin to use the timestamp in the cursor it needs to provide to the engine.

**So in summary, each plugin/migration provides the following to the engine:**

- A cursor, which optionally uses the last migrated date passed to it
  from the engine, in order to ensure that only deltas are moved
  across.
- A transform function, which the engine uses to turn each document in the cursor into a delimited string, which gets appended to an export file
- A schema file, this is a SQL file containing the schema for the table at redshift

Answer (score 2):

Redshift is a data ware housing product and Mongo DB is a NoSQL DB. Clearly, they are not a replacement of each other and can co-exist and serve different purpose. Now how to save and update records at both places.
You can move all Mongo DB data to Redshift as a one time activity.
Redshift is not a good fit for real time write. For Near Real Time Sync to Redshift, you should Modify program that writes into Mongo DB. 
Let that program also writes into S3 locations.  S3 location to redshift movement can be done on regular interval.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo DB being a document storage engine, Apache Solr, Elastic Search can be considered as possible replacements. But they do not support SQL type querying capabilities.They basically use a different filtering mechanism. For eg, for Solr, you might need to use the Dismax Filter.

On Cloud, Amazon's Cloud Search/Azure Search would be compelling options to try as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AWS DMS to migrate data to redshift now easily , you can also realtime ongoing changes with it.